# Are MySQL transactions atomic?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, innodb, myisam

I have read that transactions are atomic in MySQL (InnoDB) but when I test the next code in 5 threads they select the same ID:

```
$db->beginTransaction();

$row = $db->fetchRow("SELECT * FROM atomic WHERE selected = 0 LIMIT 1");

sleep(5);

$db->update("atomic", array('selected' => 1), "id = " . $row['id']);

$db->commit();

echo "Selected row: " . $row['id'];
```

Comment: I think you are asking about table locking, not atomicity...

Comment: That's right, thanks. (Gracias)

Comment: I guess in all the threads the variable $row gets assigned before the previous thread commit is executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a look at the [`FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) keyword in this scenario.

A simple select will not lock the selected rows, so what you are seeing in your example is perfectly normal.